# Spring Cloud Embedded Config Server with native repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a working spring boot application and I am trying to remove some properties from application.yaml file and read them from an embedded config server in the same app. At the moment, I am trying to read properties from file system through "native" profile type, and I am planning to later replace this with S3. Also, I am trying to read the configuration directly from backend repository as explained here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_embedding_the_config_server , rather than connecting through an endpoint.

> If you want to read the configuration for an application directly from
> the backend repository (instead of from the config server), you
> basically want an embedded config server with no endpoints. You can
> switch off the endpoints entirely by not using the @EnableConfigServer
> annotation (set spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true).

I have introduced following changes to my existing application to achieve this.

Added following dependencies to pom.xml

- spring-cloud-starter-config
- spring-cloud-config-server
- spring-cloud-config-client

application-dev.yaml

```
spring:
 could:
  bootstrap:
   enabled: true
```

bootstrap.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
        - type: native
          search-locations: file:C:\\Users\\chamila\\config-test\\config
#      bootstrap: true
```

The required properties are saved in a different application-dev.yaml file at the above file path. I have not used `@EnableConfigServer` annotation from my app class, as I want connect directly without the endpoint.

However, still my program is failing to read the properties from the config-server. I tried setting `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true` and `spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true` from both application-dev.yaml and bootstrap.yaml, but it didn't work?

Any idea what I am missing? I note that I never specified how to connect to the config-server in my application-dev.yaml file also. Is that an issue?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample project of an embedded Configuration Server which uses a custom repository:

- https://github.com/taxone/embedded-config-server

The initial problem was that the custom EnvironmentRepository was not available via bootstrap, [as described in this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/2129).

Answer (score 0):

I followed https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_embedding_the_config_server and achieved the expected result.

1. Add `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` to your dependencies as suggested in https://github.com/taxone/embedded-config-server.
2. Make sure that `composite` profile is active when you start the app.
3. Verify that your `native` configuration is added by finding a log message from `NativeEnvironmentRepository` during startup.
4. (Optional) Remove `spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled` from `application-dev.yaml`.
5. (Optional) Remove `spring-cloud-config-client` dependency as it is included in both `spring-cloud-starter-config` and
   `spring-cloud-config-server`.
6. (Further steps) Use `@RefreshScope` on a spring bean to achieve dynamic properties. Requires `POST actuator/refresh`.